# Assigning variable with space to html class in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, variables

I have a variable and use it for creating an HTML element with a class attribute:

```
var my_class="my_class";
$(this).after("<div class="+my_class+"></div>");
```

I get `<div class="my_class"></div>` as expected, but when adding a variable with space in it:

```
var my_class="my_class id";
$(this).after("<div class="+my_class+"></div>");
```

I get `<div class="my_class" id></div>` instead of `<div class="my_class id"></div>`. How can I change that?

Comment: Best to avoid all these pitfalls and assign the attribute directly: `$(this).after($("<div></div>").attr('class', my_class));`

Comment: String composition is the worst way to generate HTML, and this is the main reason. Note that you can use single quotes: `"<div class='"+my_class+"'></div>"` or a template literal: `\`<div class="${my_class}"></div>\`` instead.

Comment: Here's what I'd do: `const $div = $('<div>');` then `div.addClass('my_class').addClass('id');` (or both at once) then `$(this).after($div);`

Comment: Or `$("<div/>", { "class": "my_class id" })`

Answer (score 6):

You seem to be expecting that `"` is part of the HTML? Because executing (part of) your code results in the following string:

```js
const my_class="my_class id";
console.log("<div class="+my_class+"></div>");
```

That gives `<div class=my_class id></div>`, i.e. no `"` for `class`. So add them by adding escaped quotes:

```js
const my_class="my_class id";
console.log("<div class=\""+my_class+"\"></div>");
```